# Open Source PCoIP client for Unix or PCoIP client compiled for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, protocol

The [PC over IP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teradici#PCoIP_Protocol) is a proprietary protocol for controlling computers with graphical interfaces remotely *(similar to the RDP protocol of Microsoft)*
I need to use raspberry-pi as client for our servers so it would avoid buying full Windows PC.

The idea is to get a Linux binary compiled for ARMv6 or find an open-source client which I would be able to cross-compile.

Comment: I found a [PCoIP client for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmware.view.client.android). Running android apps on linux armhf would be way to do that.